# Npgsql extremely slow to open connections to Redshift

Tags: npgsql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Npgsql to connect to Amazon Redshift. This all works correctly, but it seems very slow at connecting.

Everything I'm doing seems pretty standard:

```
<add name="EventDatabase" connectionString="Server=...us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com; Database=analytics; UID=...; PWD=...; Port=...; Pooling=true; MinPoolSize=4; MaxPoolSize=12; ConnectionLifeTime=300;" />

Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventDB"].ConnectionString);
Connection.Open();
```

Benchmarking this a few times gives me an average time to open a connection of 0.9s. This is much higher than I would expect.

The connection should be pooled and I would have thought opening would be instant? Even if it's not pooled, 0.9s seems high. 40% of our query time is spent opening connections. That's not correct.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with Beta1 using Redshift. With RC1 the connection opening is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

We found that Npgsql 2.2.5 wasn't releasing connections back into the connection pool, which is exacerbated by the expensive time to create a new connection (also ~1 second each).

This was tracked down to an error:

> ERROR: 0A000: SQL command "UNLISTEN *" not supported.

Making the following change to the 2.2.5 `NpgSql/NpgSql/NpgSqlConnector.cs` code seems to rectify matters:

```
    internal void ReleaseRegisteredListen()
    {
        if (!IsRedshift) 
            NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteBlind(this, NpgsqlQuery.UnlistenAll);
    }
```

Disclaimer : This isn't fully tested, and there may be a different cleanup needed on RedShift altogether, which isn't done here.

Answer (score 0):

Append "**Pooling=False**" to the connection string, and call this before opening the connection:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(512, 512);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1024, 1024);
```